# Bits vs Char - What's the best way to store 3 mutually exclusive flags?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, char, bit

I've got a table which is set to keep track of various items.  Among other properties, items can be either A, B, or C, each mutually exclusive of the rest.  Is it best practice to store this information as a character, or as 3 sets of bits (isA isB, isC, etc), or some other method?  I could understand using the character if I would possibly need more data types in the future, however it also makes sense to me that using bit datatypes would consume smaller amounts of storage.  Or am I overanalyzing this and will the difference be so miniscule as to not even matter?

Comment: With this limited information I'd apply the "Zero, one, infinity" rule and make 1 column with three values (allowing for a fouth, fifth, etc..).  You're not losing anything anyway since "The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on."  So you lose the whole byte anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or am I overanalyzing this and will the difference be so miniscule as to not even matter?

A little bit, yes.

But you must understand that there's a crucial difference between your design proposals: having a `char` column will make exclusive exception work. Having `IsX` fields (alone) will not. Explained: by having `IsA` and `IsB` columns, you can, potentially, have both set to true in the same record, unless you use another mechanism  to prevent that (trigger, check constraint, etc.)

Additionally, having a new column every time a new value is possible is not good DB design.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Char`.

Space wise, you will be using an extra 625kb per million rows (assuming  5 bits saved per row, which is a best-case scenario savings-wise).

**That isn't very much.**

To put it into perspective, that's `625 MB` per **BILLION** rows.  When you get to tables of that size you don't care about any units that don't start with `giga`, `tera`, or `peta`.

Internally, SQL Server stores them all as a byte regardless (up to 8 bit fields).

By the time the space matters, any architecture changes (from using bit fields to something more flexible) will be extremely painful.

Comment: Didn't realize how miniscule that would be.  That's awesome information, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a single char, byte, enum, whatever.  If the states are mutually exclusive, then that isn't the best use for flags.

Answer (score 1):

Come to think of it a really tight, but kind of crazy, way to pull your scenario off would be to stored them in a nullable bit.

> "An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL."

but I don't quite see how they pull that off though since

> "The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte."

Both from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx

If you need to index on the three values I would go for a [tinyint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) instead of three bit fields.

Comment: There is a separate "null bitmap" byte (more bytes if > 8 columns) that records null values, which is how they pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [tiny int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx), basically a one byte number 0 to 255.  As you expand your possible values, you end up using crazy letters that don't mean anything.  So, I just start out with numbers.  Keeping the three bits mutually exclusive isn't worth the hassle, they'll take a byte of storage anyways.